# "bet" vs "wager"

Tags: difference

I'm watching *Suits* and in Season 1, Episode 9 the following conversation occurs:

> All right, Ben, why don't we make a bet?

> I think you mean a wager, Michael.

I understand it's a pedantic point and, for practical purposes, they're synonyms - but pedantically what is the difference between a bet and a wager? I've tried searching for it but I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: It's not a "pedantic" point - it's an *ignorant* point. There might be certain contexts where either ***bet*** or ***wager*** would be "preferred" (as ***nouns***), but in the cited context Ben just doesn't know what he's talking about - they're synonymous and interchangeable. Note that *idiomatically* today, ***I bet you*** almost everyone would use ***bet*** rather than ***wager*** in this current sentence of mine *(**as a verb**)*. And as a general rule, ***wager*** is becoming increasingly "old-fashioned" in all contexts apart from historical / fantasy narratives.

Comment: ...and as a transitive ***verb*** usage, I've never encountered *Don't **wager** the farm on it*. [That one's always ***bet***.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bet%20the%20farm%20on%20it) Equally, for the ***noun*** usage, [it's practically always ***a safe bet***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+a+safe+bet%2CIt%27s+a+safe+wager&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20%27s%20a%20safe%20bet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20%27s%20a%20safe%20wager%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I love the [Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/wager/bet) explanation: *As verbs the difference between wager and bet is that wager is to bet something; to put it up as collateral while bet is to stake or pledge upon the outcome of an event; to wager.*